# How do I get the data of a returned value from a spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am making an android application that asks a user to enter the name of a code and then the actual code itself. Once the user inputs these values and presses a submit button the inputs are passed to another class that stores them. For this so far I have used (with the unnecessary bits in between omitted):

```
EditText nameCode, dataCode;

nameCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeName);                                      
dataCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeData);

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ticketType);                                                                                  
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.codeType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);      
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);                           
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addPassCode(nameCode.getText().toString(),dataCode.getText().toString());      
        populateCodes();                                                                
    }
});

private void addPassCode(String name, String passCode) {
    PassCodes.add(new PassCode(name, passCode));
```

This part all works fine. What I am trying to do is now pass another variable as well as 'name' and 'passCode' in my addPassCode method. I have a spinner that contains an array of 3 values (Strings) and I want the user to select a value and then the equivalent of getText().toString() for a spinner input so I can add it to my method to pass it to my class 'PassCodes' storing all the data. Also how would i cast this variable similarly to the previous 2 to EditText?

Also what would be the correct variable type for ticketType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And then to set the value in your EditText, simply do:

```
dataCode.setText(text);
```

Comment: Awesome, I've implemented the first part so I've assigned the value to my own variable. The end goal of all of that is to display the name, code and type in a list view, but I'm not sure how do it for the spinner entry. I've used this for the other 2:



TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codeName);                
name.setText(currentCode.getName());
 TextView code = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userPassCode);
 code.setText(currentCode.getCode());